# What does the modulo operator mean when applied to character arithmetic?

Tags: c, modulo

```
symbol = (rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1)) + ' ';
```

I have understood that every time that i run the program "symbol" is different. But , why can't I use

```
symbol = rand();
```

Comment: Because `rand` returns a value 0-RAND_MAX (usually 32,767)... not a random symbol...

Comment: Please read the documentation, and what the `%` operator does. That should answer your question.

Comment: It produces a character in the "printable" range.

Comment: @WeatherVane beat you by whole 3 minutes. :D

Comment: @SouravGhosh I uv'ed 3 lengthy answers because I was Johnny-come-lately 9 (3 x 3) minutes after the question was posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane to honor your support, I've just made my answer _lengthier_. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh good, because at the time of my UV it was not IMO the *best* answer but now it is ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane what does UV mean?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Only for ASCII encoding and compatible.

Comment: @KamiKaze up vote.

Comment: @Olaf as you well know homage is paid to EBCDIC for legacy. I do not care what the standard says: I will never write code that is compatible with it, and neither do most other people. Although I avoid hard coding the ASCII numeric values when I can use `'A'` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane, EBCDIC is not only for legacy, there are actual systems out there that have modern C compilers that use this encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing called *character arithmatic* <sup>Note</sup> (AFAIK) and the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) means it's usual business. What you seem to be confused is about the whole expression.

As per the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

- `~` has a decimal value of 126
- has decimal value of 32.

The output of `rand()` will be modulo-valued by the range, over the *space*, so as to produce a [*printable* representation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html).

To break it down,

- `('~' - ' ' + 1)` == `126-32 +1` == `95`
- `(rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1))` produces a random number between `0-94`.
- `(rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1)) + ' '` yields a random number between `32-126`, which is the printable range.

> why I can't use `symbol = rand();`

Well, there's nothing wrong in that statement, but looks like the purpose is to produce a *printable* `symbol` value.

---

Note:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.4

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
>   in single-quotes, as in 'x'. [...]

and,

> An integer character constant has type `int`. [...]

so, it's integer arithmetic, all the way.

Comment: There is sthg wrong as you still not know the type of `symbol`. It depends from the declaration of the variable.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス 1) how is it 127? 2) True, but it appears that is not _particularly_ relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Ascii of

- `~` is 126
- `space` is 32

So `symbol = (rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1)) + ' ';` is equivalent to:

```
symbol = (rand() % (126 - 32 + 1)) + 32;
```

which gives you a **random number between `32` and `126`**

---

***C99 7.20.2.1***

> The `rand` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the
>   **range 0 to RAND_MAX**.
>
> The value of the **RAND_MAX** macro shall be **at least 32767**.

You can use `symbol=rand()` if you want a range between *0* and *min(max(32767,RAND_MAX),TYPE_SYMBOL_MAX)* and as long as **the type of `symbol` permit that**.

Answer (score 1):

Character constants in C are integers. So the following:

```
('~' - ' ' + 1)
```

Calculates the offset of the encoding for `'~'` from the encoding for `' '` and add one to it. It's how many different character encodings lie between them, let's call that number `m`.

```
(rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1))
```

Takes a pseudo-random number and maps it to the range `[0, m)`, let's call *that* number `n`.

```
(rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1)) + ' '
```

This simply takes `n`, treating it as an offset, and adds it to the encoding of `' '`, thus getting an encoding of a symbol. The symbol will always be one of a certain set.

---

```
symbol = rand();
```

The above will convert an integer, that possibly lies way outside the range of `char`, into some a character value. That will be done in some implementation defined manner. That's not the most reliable way to get correct results, to say the least.

Comment: also,  in c the rand function will work with the same value eath time you will run the program. unless you will use srand...